# Decorator Pattern com Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, repository, decorator-pattern

Galera tenho uma necessidade aqui e estou com certa dificuldade para implementar
eu tenho uma aplicação com Decorator Pattern e gostaria de atualizar os dados dos meus components pegando as informações diretamente do banco de dados, mas não estou achando uma forma legal para fazer mesmo usando o repository pattern.

Este é meu component

```
public abstract class Component
{
    public abstract string GetName();
    public abstract double GetPrice();
    public abstract string GetDescription();
    public abstract int GetMinutesToPrepare();
    public abstract int GetNumberTable();
}
```

Meu ConcreteComponent

```
namespace Restaurant.Lib.Components.MainCourse
{
    public class RoastLamb : Dishes
    {
        private string Description = "An Indian roast lamb you can't miss: learn how to prepare a roast leg of lamb indian style, marinated with mixed spices.";
        private int MinutesToPrepare = 30;
        private string Name = "Main Course - Roast Lamb With Indian Spices";
        private int NumberTable = 0;
        private double Price = 53.00;

        public RoastLamb(int numberTable)
        {
            NumberTable = numberTable;
        }

        public override int GetNumberTable() => NumberTable;
        public override string GetDescription() => Description;
        public override int GetMinutesToPrepare() => MinutesToPrepare;
        public override string GetName() => Name;
        public override double GetPrice() => Price;
    }
}
```

e esses dados acima gostaria de pegar do banco de dados.

Fiz uma camada de DAO com ado.net mesmo mas cai num problema de referência circular pois minha "Entidade" na verdade está declarada dentro do meu component que é o padrão do Decorator.

Alguém tem uma solução viável?

Comment: Existe algum motivo especial pra você usar este padrão? Achei ele bastante e desnecessariamente complexo pro objetivo que você aparentemente tem.

Comment: Minha aplicação tem como escopo um Restaurante e os pedidos resolvi fazer desta forma, por facilitar incrementar itens a um pedido por exemplo:

**Café** seria uma classe componente e **Açucar** seria um decorator para incrementar a classe café e ai aumentaria o valor e tempo de preparo. O problema que os valores são variáveis e não fixo como está.

Comment: Bom, a solução é por preenchimento externo via *Reflection*, mas eu precisaria entender melhor como é seu banco de dados e sua aplicação pra propor algo.

Comment: Ainda não tenho nada de banco por justamente ficar em duvida, minha aplicação simplesmente vai montar os pedidos instanciando as classes, por exemplo: 

   var desserts = new AppleCake(NumberTableRandom);
   var sugar = new Sugar(desserts);

Meu banco estou pensando em só manter os dados de cada component que terei e ai preencher, via reflection é interessante.

Comment: Seja sempre cauteloso quando estiver tendendo a usar reflection.
Há pouca informação, e como @CiganoMorrisonMendez falou está aparentando desnecessária essa complexidade. 
De qualquer modo, já pensou em adicionar uma nova camada antes e fazer uso de DI, Ou mesmo a criação de um proxy?